# How can I add digital signature to memorystreram using iTextSharp

Tags: itext, digital-signature

Is that possible with `iTextSharp library`, process *digital signature* and attached it with memory stream
later on return this memory stream so that if create a `PDF` file from that memory stream a digitally signed file created

```
public MemoryStream Sign(MemoryStream ms)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ms);
    //I also try 
    //PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());
    PdfStamper st = new PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', true);
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
    sap.SetCrypto(this.myCert.Akp, this.myCert.Chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
    sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), 1, null);
    return ms;
}
```

it gives error  PDF header signature not found.

Comment: Never read and write to the same thing, that will almost always break no matter what you do in life. Also, I would strongly encourage you to work with `MemoryStreams` within your methods (as you are) but only ever pass byte arrays between them. Never take a stream as input to a method and just use it blindly and never return a stream from a method and expect that the receiver will reset it correctly.

Comment: The code is utterly broken. You don't start signing a PDF using `new PdfStamper`. in your case the `PdfSignatureAppearance sap` should be null resulting I. all kind of havoc.